# Watching a phone's physical orientation with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mobile, orientation, responsive

I want to know whether the user is physically holding their screen in portrait or landscape mode, even if they have locked their screen.

I cannot use `orientationchange` events, as these won't fire if the rotation is locked. I want to follow the actual, real-world rotation of the device, not the logical orientation of the viewport.

I am aware that we should normally never force a display orientation on our users, and that we should respect users' preferences when they lock the orientation - but I really *do* have a reason to do this.

Is there ever any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - if the phone is being held upright. Then we can use `DeviceMotionEvents` to read the pull of gravity on the phone's X and Y axes:

```
function watchOrientation(subscriber) {
    if (window.DeviceMotionEvent) {
        window.addEventListener('devicemotion', eventData => {
            const hg = eventData.accelerationIncludingGravity.x;
            const vg = eventData.accelerationIncludingGravity.y;

            if (vg > 5) {
                subscriber('up');
            } else if (vg <= -5) {
                subscriber('down');
            } else if (hg > 0) {
                subscriber('left');
            } else if (hg <= 0) {
                subscriber('right');
            }

        }, true);
    } else {
        console.warn('Device does not support "devicemotion" events');
    }
}
```

Obviously, this won't work if the phone is held flat or laid on a table. In that case your only chance is to use the compass data in a `DeviceOrientationEvent` (but only if you already know whether your user is facing North!)